# How to select only missing values for testing the model?

Tags: python, regression, logistic-regression

I am working on logistic regression project where I have 850 observations and 8 variables and in this, I found 150 missing values and I have decided to use these values as test data. How can I take only missing values as test data in python?

I am still learning data science if there's a mistake in this approach please let me know.

Thank you :)

Comment: where's your code???

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `pd.isna()` from pandas library.

It will return a boolean array that you can use for filtering your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all rows, having any missing value in that, using following code

```
df[df.isnull().values.any(axis=1)]
```

I do not recommend you to use all data with missing values for testing. You should either fill the missing values completely or at least partial values should be filled in the test dataset. 
Let's see what other Machine Learning experts advise you.